# Convert image on from grayscale to black and while (1-bit palette)

Tags: command-line, gimp

How do I convert a image on from grayscale to black and while (1-bit palette) using command line tools?

My new scanner only scan color or grayscale, and not "lineart", so I'm finding my self open gimp and selecting "Image -> Mode -> Indexed" and then "Use black and white (1-bit) palette"
on quite a lot of images.

So I'm searching for a command line tool that can do this without any gui.

There seems to be some support in gimp itself to do this

```
gimp-console --batch=<command>
```

But I'm not sure how to use this "gimp-console".

Thanks
Johan

---

***Note***: I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ImageMagick:

```
convert input.png -monochrome output.png
```

It has plenty of options to further adjust output.